# Should I put my modal in my django views or through the html?

Tags: html, django

I am trying to figure out wether it would be easier to implement a modal/alert system from my views.py or through the html. Currently, I have a matching system where users like or dislike each other, and if they like each other, I send them to another html and it says they matched and can message each other. I'd like to do that through a modal or alert. I am thinking it would be easier to implement that through the views.py, but I don't know how to do it, I only know how to do it through html. But through html, I'm not sure how to compare the vote values between each user like I do in my views. What should I do? I currently have mingle.html which is where users like and dislike each other, and then if they both like each other, it sends them to match.html.

**views.py/CreateVote**

```
@login_required
def create_vote(request, profile_id, vote):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=profile_id)

    
    UserVote.objects.create(
        user=profile,
        voter=request.user,
        vote=vote
    )
    other = UserVote.objects.filter(
        voter=profile,
        user=request.user,
        vote=True
    )
    if vote and other.exists():
        profile.matches.add(request.user)
        request.user.matches.add(profile)
        return render(request, 'dating_app/match.html', dict(
                match=profile,
            ))
    return redirect('dating_app:mingle')
```

**mingle.html**

```
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% if profile %}
<section>
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-3">
                <div class="card profile-card-5">
                    <div class="card-img-block">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ profile.photo.url  }}" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body pt-0">
                    <h5  class="card-title">{{profile.username}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{profile.description}}.</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'dating_app:nice' profile.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</a>
                    <a href="{% url 'dating_app:nope' profile.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Dislike</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% else %}
        <br><br>
        <p>Wait for more people to join!</p>
        <p>Help us get more user. Share this link to your friends! <a href="http://localhost:8000/">http://localhost:8000/</a></p>
{% endif %}

<br/>
```

**match.html**

```
   {% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<style>
.col-4 {
    display: inline-block;
    }
</style>



<div class="container ">
    <h2>It's a match!</h2>
    <div class = "row">
        
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                
                 <img src="{{ user.photo.url }}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                
                 <img 

src="{% static 'images/matching_cupid.png' %}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
               
                 <img src="{{ match.photo.url }}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >
                
            </div>
        
    </div>
    <p>You and {{ match.username }} like each other!</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'dating_app:messages' user.id %}">Start messaging </a></p>
    <br>
    <p><a href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Keep mingling!</a></p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: return what to show in your view and use javascript/html how to show it so to say. So e.g. use your view to return a boolean "is.matched = true/false" and render the modal depending on the returned value using javascript or any modal library.

Comment: Ok, that gives me an idea. I don't have any idea how to implement it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a message via the Django built-in [message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/) and render that out in your `dating_app/match.html`.

You already got the necessary view logic here:

```
# Import the framework
from django.contrib import messages


[...]
# In this case deliver a message along with the template
if vote and other.exists():
        profile.matches.add(request.user)
        request.user.matches.add(profile)
        
        # Add message
        messages.add_message(request, 'You have a match!')

        return render(request, 'dating_app/match.html', dict(
                match=profile,
            ))
    return redirect('dating_app:mingle')
[...]
```

In your **match.html** you render the message like so:

```
[...]

<div id="match_message">{{ message }}</div>

[...]
```

Javascript for alert

```
// Dont forget to import jQuery and link the js file in your html file

$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( {{ message }} );
});
```

Comment: So it would basically show up as a 'pop-up' then you're saying?

Comment: as of now no, as a plain html container. If you want a simple pop-up just fire an alert on pageload and insert the {{ message }} in the alert :) I edited my answer

Comment: So then what's the point of adding the code you put as an answer? What does it actually do?

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to have a pop up like tinder does when you match with someone

Comment: as mentioned earlier, it is up to css/javascript manipulation how you finally want to display and style the message. Either as alert, modal, or a custom html container popping up with position absolute. But this isn't part of this question. I encourage you to open a new post for the styling stuff :)